# React Native Firebase Auth keeps on failing I have followed all the necessary steps

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

So I have downloaded react-native-firebase using npm i @react-native-firebase/auth and it is sucessfully registered in my package.json file.
I have added the google-services plugin to my android directory as directed by the website.
[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO3gJ.png)

Than after that I have added this line in /android/build.gradle

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
```

Than after that I have added the plugin to in /android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Still I am getting error

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'F:\Salvador\node_modules@react-native-firebase\auth\android\build.gradle' line: 29
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-firebase_auth'.

> Could not find the react-native-firebase/app package, have you installed it?

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-firebase_auth'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 46s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'F:\Salvador\node_modules@react-native-firebase\auth\android\build.gradle' line: 29
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-firebase_auth'.

> Could not find the react-native-firebase/app package, have you installed it?

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-firebase_auth'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 46s

```
at makeError (F:\Salvador\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at F:\Salvador\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (F:\Salvador\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (F:\Salvador\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: I have also tried deleting node_modules folder and npm install everything and nothing happens I still get the same error.

Comment: can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are still struggling to find the answer just

```
npm i @react-native-firebase/app
```

and you are good to go.  Took me a day